# Sum of the product of distinct counts in SQL?

Tags: sql, sum

Suppose you have the following two tables A and B:

(NOTE: I am unable to enter the table so please transpose the comma delimited tables.)

**Table A**

```
pid   cost
1     2
1     2 
2     1 
3     5 
3     5 
3     5
4     10
4     10
5     7
```

**Table B**

```
pid   perid
1     3
2     3 
3     6 
4     5 
5     1
```

Where pid matches in the two tables.  Here is what I need to accomplish in SQL.  I need to find the total cost for each pid, and this needs to get associated with and grouped by perid.  It will probably need a count done on each distinct pid. So the resulting answer should be something like:

```
perid   cost
1       7
3       5
5       20 
6       15
```

Comment: please **format** the question properly (especially table)...

Answer (score 4):

Here's the stuff:

```
select
  b.period,
  sum(cost)
from b
inner join a
  on b.pid = a.pid
group by b.period
```

and [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17b57/7)

Comment: And yes, you better provide some codes before asking a question :)

Comment: And yes, you better first ask [`what you have tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Great solution. I just tried it and it worked as expected.  Thank you!